# /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables script makeeth interfaces disappear in debian jessie?

Tags: networking, debian, iptables

I need to enable NAT on my VM in iptables. I followed [official debian instruction](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables)  to configure it:

First of all, i created /etc/iptables.rules file with following content:
    *nat
    -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 46.4.120.218
    COMMIT

After i use `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules` manually, nat rules are added fine, everything works

But when i try to autoload iptables rules via file `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables` with following content eth interfaces disappear (i can see only loopback interface via ifconfig):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

I tried to do the same on debian wheezy and this was working. In debian jessie this does not work. Is it my mistake, or bug?

P.S. I tried to move iptables script to `if-up.d` folder, eth interfaces are present in this case, but iptables rules are not applied.

Comment: Did you try to set `post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables` in the section of that interface your `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen finally i resolved my problem via /etc/network/interfaces config with `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules` line